Process keeps resetting the new position of an object in godot
The ResetMobPosition is being called in every frame in the Process callback function, but I only want it to be called once, if the position matches one of the conditions in the CheckMobPositions is there any pattern that I could use so that I can only call it once?
private void CheckMobPositions(Mobs mob){
    float viewportWidth = GetViewport().GetVisibleRect().Size.X;
    float viewportHeight = GetViewport().GetVisibleRect().Size.Y;
    float min = viewportWidth;
    float max = viewportWidth+300;
    Vector2 oppositePosition = new (viewportWidth - 300, GD.Randf() * viewportHeight - 300);
    Vector2 startingPosition = new (200, GD.Randf() * viewportHeight - 300);

    if(mob.Position.X < 0){
    ResetMobPosition(mob,oppositePosition);
    return;
    }else if(mob.Position.X > viewportWidth ){
    ResetMobPosition(mob,startingPosition);
    };
}

// This is being called per frame which resets the position over and over again,
// need to only call this once only after if the mob position is checked.
public void ResetMobPosition(Mobs mob, Vector2 newDirection ){
    Mobs outBoundsMob = mobsArray.Find(subMob=> subMob.GetIndex() ==  mob.GetIndex());
    outBoundsMob.Position = newDirection;
}

public override void _Process(double delta){
    MoveMobs();
}


Created a PubSub pattern to publish an event if a mob is out of bounds, still the same.


First Thing first: Try using global position instead of the local position. And debug the positions with pring logs. if its called every process frame one of your conditions is always true, or you missed some more infos.
